# Equivalent of BASH_XTRACEFD redirection in Python

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

How can I emulate the following BASH script in Python2.7 ? (Redirection of commands that ran to some file):

```
exec 3> >(sed -e 's/^[+]* /[BASH] /' >> code_that_ran.tmp) 
export BASH_XTRACEFD=3
set -x
```

What I tried:

```
$ python -m trace -t prog.py
```

Problem is I need the trace to be run inside the script so I could redirect it to a file, perform some logic on it and not on the python execution line as said above

Thanks!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description:

> I need the trace to be run inside the script so I could redirect it to a file

```
$ python -m trace -t prog.py
```

This will output trace result into stdout, I suppose you want to store that result into file. Below is an example based on the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html#trace.Trace.runfunc).

**prog.py**

```
def main():
    pass

if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

**trace_run.py**

```
import sys
import trace
import imp

# create a Trace object, telling it what to ignore, and whether to do tracing or line-counting or both.
tracer = trace.Trace(
    ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
    trace=0,
    count=1)

# load target program dynamically
target = imp.load_source(sys.argv[1], './'+sys.argv[1])

# run the main function of program using the given tracer
tracer.runfunc(target.main)

# make a report, placing output in the current directory
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir=".")
```

then simply run `python trace_run.py prog.py`

**prog.cover**

```
>>>>>> def main():
    1:     pass

>>>>>> if "__main__" == __name__:
>>>>>>     main()
```